# How to write complex formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I write this formula in Excel?  I have written f(x), but I have problem with g(x).

[image]

Where x belongs in [-2,2]. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi mn93, since `n` is small, you should consider writing each part of the sum separately. Plus could you show how you  wrote `f(x)` (in your question)? And also, what is `f'(x)`? This must be an easy derivate, but I forgot wich? is it `1/(3+x)` or something?

Comment: Yes, the derivative f'(x) is 1/(3+x). You can use the FACT function to get n! and the POW function or ^ symbol to get n raised to a power..

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use those functions, but I don't know how to sum all this in one function? I have problem with the sum, I don't know how to combine all of this in excel.

Comment: Sorry, meant POWER function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Formulas:

`B2` downwards:

```
=LN(3+A2)
```

`E2` to right and downwards:

```
=1/(3+$A2)/FACT(E$1)*POWER($A2,E$1)
```

`C2` downwards:

```
=SUM(E2:J2)
```

`L2` downwards:

```
=SUM(1/(3+$A2)/FACT({1;2;3;4;5;6})*POWER($A2,{1;2;3;4;5;6}))
```

Two approaches here. First is using helper columns for calculating the single terms of the `SUM`. Second is using array literals `{1;2;3;4;5;6}` for `n`.

Comment: I agreed with your answers and used helper columns in the same way :-)

Comment: I used the second approach. Thanks a lot!